# How to view the latest Google Stackdriver logs without scrolling through all logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

In the case that you have many pages of logs, it seems that you must scroll through every single entry before you can view the most recent. Clicking 'jump to time', or selecting the current time only displays a blank page. How is one to sift through a large set of logs to get the most recent? Am I missing something here?

I've heard that with some google services (ie App Engine) this is not true, but with Google Cloud Functions this seems to be the case that it is nearly impossible to view recent logs.

Comment: I just refresh the page first and then press Page Down until I hit the newest entries.

Comment: Yes, but imagine you have an entire month of logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near `Jump to now` there is an drop down menu. By default this menu is set to `No limit`. Click and choose `Custom`, set the `Start date` and then the `End date`. After this, it will refresh the LOGs and will show you the LOGs for the selected date range.

Comment: at first I thought that didn't work, but I think it does actually!